# How to seperate COPY to multiple steps for caching in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building an Docker image with big files (>1.0GB) and small python scripts. Big files are rarely changed, so I want to caching it.

The directory is looks like:

```
- app/
  - main.py
  - modules/
      - foo.py
      - bar.py
  - big_files/
      - bigone.tar
      - bigtwo.tar
```

My first Dockerfile:

```
FROM python3:latest
COPY ./app /opt/app
```

When I update python scripts, it have to COPY all files which consume a long time.

What I want to acheive:

```
FROM python3:latest
COPY ./app/big_files /opt/app/big_files
COPY ./app /opt/app
```

However, it also copy big files too.

How to COPY in two step for caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your app's structure so that the big files are outside the /app folder.

If you don't want to do that, then you have to explicitly copy the files under /app:

```
FROM python3:latest
COPY ./app/big_files /opt/app/big_files
COPY ./app/*.py /opt/app/
COPY ./app/modules /opt/app/
```

Answer (score 0):

Each step is happening in its own layer. In your case that means

1. Pull base image
2. Copy Big Files
3. Copy ./app

Everything **must** be run on the initial build.

With a setup similar to yours:

```bash
$ tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
└── app
    ├── bigFiles
    │   └── bigFile
    └── smallFile
```

and a dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

COPY ./app/bigFiles .
COPY ./app .

RUN echo 'Done'
```

Now if you run the exact same build again and nothing has changed, each layer can be reused:

```bash
$ docker build -t stackoverflowtest .

[+] Building 1.4s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1.3s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 124B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:latest@sha256:e9c35537103a2801a30b15a77d4a56b35532c964489b125ec1ff24f3d5b53409                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY ./app/bigFiles .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY ./app .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] RUN echo 'Done'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:a78f5f730a893ccaaff102a7fe179461ec15c53bcbac926cb818e95d9d012875                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/stackoverflowtest
```

If you touch the big files, that layer has to be rebuilt:

```
$ echo "Change me" > app/bigFiles/bigFile
$ docker build -t stackoverflowtest .
[+] Building 0.9s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 146B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:latest@sha256:e9c35537103a2801a30b15a77d4a56b35532c964489b125ec1ff24f3d5b53409                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [2/4] COPY ./app/bigFiles .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [3/4] COPY ./app .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [4/4] RUN echo 'Done'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:912022e447d8af0d20d77bc0ea41e0e1451012e1185e97e58f13409b6542bc19                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/stackoverflowtest
```

You can see that in the example above, the step 2 *and* 3 have changed because `bigFiles` is also part of `app`, so no layer could be cached.

However, if you only change the small files and not big files, the big file layer can be cached:

```
$ echo "Change me" > app/smallFile
$ docker build -t stackoverflowtest .
[+] Building 0.9s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.6s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:latest@sha256:e9c35537103a2801a30b15a77d4a56b35532c964489b125ec1ff24f3d5b53409                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 148B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY ./app/bigFiles .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [3/4] COPY ./app .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [4/4] RUN echo 'Done'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:fdb687373689497d81bd6a14d4c30c6586b613b25463cdf5b387475700ccfb07                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/stackoverflowtest
```

Comment: Although big files were copied in the second step, it takes a long time in the third step because big files are also copied in the third step too.